# Trying to load/execute two table values at the same time

Tags: php, mysql, href

I'm trying to create a page that displays content from database when specific title is selected, and all the comments added to it (only comments for the selected title should be visible) by other users. I want make the id and review_id to work together on the same line. I cant create two separate echo's as it creates two separate titles.

I've tried to link the values together but cant make it work.

```
echo '<li><a href="showreview.php?id=' . $comment['id'] . '">' . $comment['name'] . ' - ' . $comment['date'] . '</a></li>'; 
'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
echo '<li><a href="showreview.php?review_id=' . $comment['id'] . '">' . $comment['name'] . ' - ' . $comment['date'] . '</a></li>';
```

Is there a way to make "id" and "review_id" work at the same line ?

Comment: Just echo it all together.
Will it work:
echo '<li><a href="showreview.php?id=' . $comment['id'] . '">' . $comment['name'] . ' - ' . $comment['date'] . '</a></li>.<li><a href="showreview.php?review_id=' . $comment['id'] . '">' . $comment['name'] . ' - ' . $comment['date'] . '</a></li>';
?

Comment: Unfortunately no, it still shows as two separate.